# "First defined here" error

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, qt-creator

I have an error that i can't include my header file in more than  one cpp even though i have guard headers.
when removing the include of DatabaseManager from main the ccode builds just fine

here is the header file :

```
#ifndef DATABASEMANAGER_H
#define DATABASEMANAGER_H
#include <QSqlDatabase>
#include <QSqlQuery>
class DatabaseManager
{
 private:
    QSqlDatabase PatternLibrary;
    QSqlQuery query;
 public:
  DatabaseManager();
};
#endif
```

here is the .cpp:

```
#include "DatabaseManager.h"
#include <QSqlError>
#include <QDebug>

DatabaseManager::DatabaseManager()
{
}
```

and here is the main :

```
#include "DatabaseManager.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    DatabaseManager x;
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

giving these errors :

> /Code/DB_RangePattern-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_1_in_PATH_*System*_Debug/../DB_RangePattern/main.cpp:6: error: first defined here
>
> collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: You're using a [reserved identifier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier).

Comment: That's only one line of a larger error.

Comment: @Undergraduate `_DATABASEMANAGER_H` is reserved because it begins with an underscore followed by a capital letter.

Comment: even with no underscores it still gives the same error

Comment: @Undergraduate As I said, that's only one line of the error. You need to post the other lines.

Comment: @sftrabbit that's all the errors i am getting

Comment: You have `DataBaseManager x;`, but your class name is `DatabaseManager`. Is this a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've only posted one line of a larger error, but I can hazard a guess at what the problem is. You seem to be unsure of whether your class is `DataBaseManager` or `DatabaseManager` (note the change in capital `B`).

Also, if your header file is with the rest of your source files, make sure you're doing `#include "DatabaseManager.h"` (not using `<` and `>`).

Comment: even though these problem actually exists i confused the file name with the class name but even after fixing them the errors still exist :/

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure QSqlDatabase uses/include QSqlError because it has a defined public function

```
QSqlError   lastError () const
```

and redefinition will come from your including QSqlError

Comment: but when removing this include it gives this error

error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct QSqlError'

Comment: You may want to start commenting out functions & Includes until you get to a state it compiles and works, then readd and debug as you find those link issues.

Comment: i should've mentioned when removing the DatabaseManager include in main the code compiles with no errors